# How to aggregate booking numbers from two different years for comparison in a single table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm writing a report that can monitor booking numbers for an event this coming June, but which also compares the booking numbers from the same event held last year, on a day-by-day basis.

The report needs to aggregate the number of bookings by date, it needs to do the same for last year's event but adjust the booking date so it can be compared to this year, and I'm looking for a table that puts these figures side by side in a table.

So,

This code gives me the running booking totals for this year:

```
--2016 Bookings
SELECT CAST(ep.CREATIONDATE AS DATE) AS 'Booking Date', 
COUNT(ep.CREATIONDATE) as '2016 Saturday Bookings'
FROM EVENTPLACE as ep
LEFT OUTER JOIN EVENTMODULE as em ON em.EVENTMODULENO=ep.EVENTMODULENO
WHERE em.DESCRIPTION = 'Open Day'
AND em.STARTDATE = '2016.11.06'
GROUP BY CAST(ep.CREATIONDATE AS DATE)
```

And this next piece of code gives me the running total for last year's event bookings, adjusted by 364 days so that I can compare booking numbers against the comparative same day leading up to the event (accounts for the event being held on 13th June last year, compared to 11th June this year):

```
--2015 Bookings
SELECT CAST(DATEADD (d,364,ep.CREATIONDATE) AS DATE) AS 'Booking Date',
COUNT(ep.CREATIONDATE) as '2015 Saturday Bookings'
FROM EVENTPLACE as ep
LEFT OUTER JOIN EVENTMODULE as em ON em.EVENTMODULENO=ep.EVENTMODULENO
WHERE em.DESCRIPTION = 'Open Day'
AND em.STARTDATE = '2015.13.06'
GROUP BY CAST(DATEADD (d,364,ep.CREATIONDATE) AS DATE)
```

Basically, how do I 'glue' this code together so that I get a table with a 'Booking Date' column on the left with a running list of 'harmonised' 2016 dates, a column with the 2016 booking totals alongside these dates, and a column for the comparative 2015 booking totals also alongside these dates?

Greatly appreciate any pointers.

Thanks
Jon

Comment: Full outer join (to include possible missing dates) by BookingDate perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Inner join over the dates for both the tables should help(if we can be sure that all the dates are present in each table). Refer to the given code

Edit Log:
I changed the queries, since you mentioned that you are not very comfortable with Temp variables (and possibly sub queries).

```
--2016 Bookings
SELECT CAST(ep.CREATIONDATE AS DATE) AS 'Booking Date', 
COUNT(ep.CREATIONDATE) as '2016 Saturday Bookings'
INTO #2016_Bookings
FROM EVENTPLACE as ep
LEFT OUTER JOIN EVENTMODULE as em ON em.EVENTMODULENO=ep.EVENTMODULENO
WHERE em.DESCRIPTION = 'Open Day'
AND em.STARTDATE = '2016.11.06'
GROUP BY CAST(ep.CREATIONDATE AS DATE)

--2015 Bookings
SELECT CAST(DATEADD (d,364,ep.CREATIONDATE) AS DATE) AS 'Booking Date',
COUNT(ep.CREATIONDATE) as '2015 Saturday Bookings'
INTO #2015_Bookings
FROM EVENTPLACE as ep
LEFT OUTER JOIN EVENTMODULE as em ON em.EVENTMODULENO=ep.EVENTMODULENO
WHERE em.DESCRIPTION = 'Open Day'
AND em.STARTDATE = '2015.13.06'
GROUP BY CAST(DATEADD (d,364,ep.CREATIONDATE) AS DATE)

--Join to publish both records in the same table
SELECT #2016_Bookings.[Booking Date],
       #2015_Bookings.[2015 Saturday Bookings],
       #2016_Bookings.[2016 Saturday Bookings]
FROM #2016_Bookings
INNER JOIN #2015_Bookings
    ON DATEPART(dd, #2016_Bookings.[Booking Date]) = DATEPART(dd, #2015_Bookings.[Booking Date])
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Shubham. I'm afraid the syntax doesn't appear to be correct; I've tried running this but the INNER JOIN statement is problematic - possibly in the wrong place?

Comment: @Jon295087 Yes, i had made a small mistake, sorry :D

Comment: Greatly appreciate your help thanks Shubham. I've not used temp variables before, but running the revised code throws the following error: 

Msg 4121, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot find either column "Temp" or the user-defined function or aggregate "Temp.DATEPART", or the name is ambiguous.'

Please can you advise how to edit this?

Comment: Hi, @Jon295087 I edited the query to be a bit more descriptive, tell me if you require more help.

Comment: Many thanks. I'm afraid it doesn't appear to work correctly - it populates numbers in every table row for both years, even for 2016 dates that are in the future.

Comment: That could probably be attributed to your queries for individual bookings resulting in such values. Try adding a filter of DATEPART(m, #2016_Bookings.[Booking Date]) = 6 (or whatever month you may require), in a where clause after the inner join.